# firebase storage User does not have permission to access this object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

My first try at Firebase Storage, uploading an image, was successful. 
My try at downloading the image failed with the following error:
    `StorageException` has occurred.
    User does not have `permission` to access this 
    object.
    Code: `-13021 HttpResult: 403`
At the suggestions from responses to the same problem, I changed the Rules to:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
  match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write;
 }
 }
 }
```

Although I continue uploading images, I still get the same error messages downloading.
I do not want to use Authentication yet since I am in the early stages of development and depend on other colleagues to access for testing.
My code is below:

```
public class Cloud_Storage extends Activity {
private FirebaseStorage storage = 
FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
ImageView imageView;
Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle 
savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView
(R.layout.activity_cloud__storage);
    context = getApplicationContext();


    StorageReference storageReference = 
storage.getReference();
    StorageReference pathReference = 
storageReference.child              
("images/2018.03.01.16:29:578649973]// 
    imageView = (ImageView) 
 findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    // Load the image using Glide
    Context context;
    Glide.with(this.context)
            .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
            .load(storageReference)
            .into(imageView);

     }
    }
```

As I am an enthused beginner at firestore/firebase, I appreciate any comments and criticisms offered.

Comment: the problem is in your pathReference

Comment: You are right! Thanks

Comment: @rosey did you find a solution ?

Comment: I had the same problem and for me it was because I didn't configure app check service in firebase